# Is there a way to use an image as a bash alias without using the "FROM foo AS bar" syntax?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have the following at the top of my Dockerfile.template:

```
FROM nginx:alpine AS server
```

And somewhere lower in the file I have:

```
COPY --from=server /etc/nginx /etc/nginx
```

Is there a way to accomplish this **without using the `FROM foo AS bar` syntax?**

**I am stuck with a version of Docker (17.03.2-ce) that does not support that syntax.**

Is there a way to create the bash alias `server` referencing the `nginx:alpine` image without `AS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is syntax for multistage build and you have old Docker version for that. See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/:

> Multi-stage builds are a new feature requiring Docker 17.05 or higher on the daemon and client.